# Compile and Update Flutter's Dart Dart Virtual Machine with custom source code

Tags: android, flutter, dart, compilation, virtual-machine

We want to replicate the hot reloading functionality of Flutter but without having to interact with an editor's console but instead with a UI. How can we compile the flutter code and access the dart Virtual Machine manually to edit the source code that was changed instead of rebuilding the entire APK or APP?